# "Vouchsafe" defined as to give in a gracious or condescending manner

Tags: meaning

NOAD defines *vouchsafe*as

> verb [ with two objs. ]
>  give or grant (something) to (someone) in
>   a gracious or condescending manner: it is a blessing vouchsafed him by
>   heaven. 
> • [ with obj. ] reveal or disclose (information): you'd
>   never vouchsafed that interesting tidbit before.

Aren't "gracious" and "condescending" antonyms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Aren't gracious and condescending antonyms?

Not originally. Indeed, it remains that one meaning of *to condescend* is to forgo rank or privilege and join people "below" you as equals.

This was so often used ironically, of someone **acting** as if they were talking to an inferior, that it became the predominant sense.

*Vouchsafe* underwent the same partial change, and can mean either bestowing something from a superior position (which would be a graceful act), or else *as if* from a superior position. So it can be used both to match the old sense of *condescend*, or the new.

The really confusing sense, is that sometimes people talk of "vouchsafing prayers to God", which matches neither sense. My guess is that it's a matter of people only knowing *vouchsafe* from religious contexts (God is often vouchsafing, or being asked to vouchsafe something, in religious writing) understanding that it means "give", but not understanding the implied imbalance of the transaction.

Edit: Or another possibility is it was originally from asking saints to vouchsafe to intercede with God, on the matter of the prayer, among those denominations that believe in intercession of saints. Still no more than a guess.

Comment: +1 for historical context. I had no idea that "condescend" did not used to be condescending.

Comment: @terdon *condescend* still isn't always condescending, and can be condescending. It's much rarer now, though, and normally *condescend* is only condescending, these days.

Comment: @terdon  Condescension is like charity, which bears the same double sense. Both sorts of action are contemptible only when being seen to perform is more significant than the performance itself.

Comment: Re that last paragraph - Shakespeare [used "vouchsafe" several times](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Headwords-Instance.aspx?Ref=7232), the last one in that list being *"Vouchsafe my prayer"* from *The Tempest*. It would be a bad guess indeed that supposes we know better than Shakespeare how he "should" be using the word!

Comment: @FumbleFingers That clearly marks my guess as wrong, and also makes it all the more interesting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *thou* and *thy* were used of God in the days when one would not address a superior with them (indeed, addressing God remains their main survival as much liturgy retains it and forms of the scriptures that use it are still heavily used). I wonder if there could be any connection, though it's a vague wondering, with nowt to support it.

Comment: @Jon: *Thou* (but not *thy*) occurs in just one of the 11 instances I linked to (Cardinal Pandulph addressing King Philip in King John III). Whatever - I was wrong to suggest [Shakespeare's usage](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/tempest/page_50.html) in *The Tempest* is at odds with your last paragraph - it's just the standard non-ironic sense of *[please] **allow/permit/indulge** my prayer*, which isn't the same thing as the "confusing usage" you're talking about.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I meant I wondered if the use of *thou* and the use of *vouchsafe* with God going against the norm in the face of difference in status was analogous rather directly connected. But yes, after actually looking at that use, I'm going back to my original guess (still no more than a guess though).

Comment: oic. I could only find half-a-dozen instances of ["vouchsafe to God"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22vouchsafe+to+God%22&oq=%22vouchsafe+to+God%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l2.698&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on the whole Net, though, so it doesn't seem to be *that* common a mistake for a word that I bet millions of Anglophones don't really know the precise meaning of.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I spend an above-average amount of time reading religious materials, and not just of my own tradition (which doesn't have a god called "God"). Even with that, I wouldn't say it's common just that it stands out as at odds with how I understand the word from elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Yes they are. The difference here is in how vouchsafe is used. If something were vouchsafed to you by a king, it would be in a gracious manner. If it were vouchsafed to you by one of your peers, use of *vouchsafe* would indicate condescension.

Essentially, the word means that something was granted to you. If it were granted by someone who obviously has more power than you, than it will be understood to have been done in a graceful manner. If you use the word to refer to someone who is at the same social, economic or power level as you, then it would be taken as ironic and suggest a condescending manner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are antonyms, the opposite of each other. The description of vouchsafe says, as you've stated, 'in a gracious OR condescending manner,' so one or the other.

Comment: The trouble is that the next usage of _or_ by NOAD is the not-so-contrastive one:  _reveal or disclose_.